# Wordpress upload file action hook

Tags: uploads, hooks, actions

I have a custom post type called "Magazine" shown in the admin interface. Everytime a user **uploads** a **file** in the wp-admin to my custom post type "Magazine", I want to fire a hook because I have to process the file.

Is there any **action hook** I can use in this case?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: do you want to resize image?

Comment: no I want to check if the uploaded file is a pdf which I want to send to a webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, should work well

```
function cpt_from_attachment($attachment_ID)
    {          
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $attachment_post = get_post( $attachment_ID );

    $type = get_post_mime_type($attachment_ID);

    // DO WHAT YOU NEED
}

add_action("add_attachment", 'cpt_from_attachment');
```